# is it possible to colour a rectangle in folium python

Tags: python, folium

I have a map:

```
map_osm = folium.Map(location=[51.366975, 0.039039],zoom_start=12)
map_osm
```

I want to be able to add a rectangle marker that I can colour according to some statistic. I found a `polygon_marker` (http://bl.ocks.org/wrobstory/5609786) but receive the error `'Map' object has no attribute 'polygon_marker'` when I try:

```
map_osm.polygon_marker(location=[45.5132, -122.6708], popup='Hawthorne Bridge',
                     fill_color='#45647d', num_sides=4, radius=10)
```

In the final product, I would like to have lots of rectangles colour coded.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 5):

After little digging into the the docs and source code and quick experimentation, you can just input parameter `fill_color='blue'` when you initialize `Rectangle` object.

Example code:

```
m = folium.Map(
    location=[-6.237933179178703, 106.81783770824106],
    zoom_start=13,
    tiles='Stamen Toner'
)

folium.Rectangle(bounds=points, color='#ff7800', fill=True, fill_color='#ffff00', fill_opacity=0.2).add_to(m)
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Just wanted to mention what the documentation says about the `bounds` parameter: `bounds (list of points (latitude, longitude)) – Latitude and Longitude of line (Northing, Easting)`

Comment: Just an example on how to use it:
   
    `upper_left = (latMax, longMin)`
    `upper_right = (latMax, longMax)`
    `lower_right = [latMin, longMax]`
    `lower_left = (latMin, longMin)`

    `bounds = [upper_left, upper_right, lower_right, lower_left]`

Answer (score 3):

A little more research, I found:

```
grid_pt=(51.4,0.05)
W=grid_pt[1]-0.005
E=grid_pt[1]+0.005
N=grid_pt[0]+0.005
S=grid_pt[0]-0.005


upper_left=(N,W)
upper_right=(N,E)
lower_right=(S,E)
lower_left=(S,W)
line_color='red'
fill_color='red'
weight=2
text='text'
edges = [upper_left, upper_right, lower_right, lower_left]
map_osm = folium.Map(location=[latty, longy],zoom_start=14)
map_osm.add_child(folium.vector_layers.Polygon(locations=edges, color=line_color, fill_color=fill_color,
                                              weight=weight, popup=(folium.Popup(text))))
```

this works to add a single rectangle, then loop to get more